# Unity background sprite hurting fps

Tags: android, performance, unity-game-engine, 2d, 2d-games

I am making a 2d game in Unity.
when i put a background sprite that will cover the whole screen it drops my frame rate from 60 to about 40 on my android device (galaxy tab).this is really strange i would not expect this degrade in performance from a single sprite. Did any body else encounter this?

Answer (score 2):

A large sprite can absolutely affect frame rate, especially if the image you use matches the display resolution. It can also vary per device, as not all GPUs are equal - higher resolution displays with lower-end GPUs are bad in these cases.

To minimize the performance impact you try the following:

1. Ensure that alpha blending is disabled before rendering the background image. Rendering a large image (even one without any alpha) while alpha blending is enabled will affect your framerate severely.
2. Remove all background "clearing" operations (those that clear the frame buffer). These are redundant since your image will cover the entire background (effectively clearing it).
3. Use a smaller image and stretch it to fit the entire background (use filtering to smooth out the enlargement).
4. Use lower bits per pixel (such as 16 bit) for the image.

All of these impact performance to some degree.

Numbers 1 and 2 are essentially "free" optimizations, which you should definitely implement. Numbers 3 and 4 will degrade the quality of your image, but may improve your framerate - it will be up to you to decide whether the tradeoff in quality is worth the speed improvement.

Comment: ok thank you. the profiler does indicate that it may have something to do with alpha blending.